# Merge dataframe and cbind list

Tags: r, merge, cbind

I extracted from a data set the addition, maximum, and average value of a variable `y` jointly with the maximum value of `x`.

I also get the `x` value at maximum `y` value.

I pooled these values using `cbind` function. I want to `merge` this list with a dataframe, but got

```
error:Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Also, I tried the `unlist` function but didn´t gives me satistafctory data.

Here is the code I am using:

```
AUC<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) sum(d$y))
max.y<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) max(d$y))
max.x<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) max(d$x))
auc.mean<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) mean(d$y))
x.ymax<-lapply(split(data_example, data_example$class), function(d) 
d$x[which.max(d$y)])

data1<-cbind(AUC,max.y,max.x, auc.mean, x.ymax)

datafinal<-merge(data1, data_merge, by="class")
```

Here I uploaded the data for reproduce the example:

http://www.filedropper.com/dataexample_1 
http://www.filedropper.com/datamerge

Comment: You are trying to `cbind` list elements.  Perhaps you need `data1 <-  data.frame(AUC = unlist(AUC),max.y = unlist(max.y), max.x = unlist(max.x), auc.mean = unlist(auc.mean), x.ymax = unlist(x.ymax), class = names(AUC))`

Comment: Thanks, I posted my comment as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `cbind` didn't work is because the objects were `list`s.  There are couple of ways to correct this

**1)** Replace `lapply` with `sapply` to get a `vector` output

```
AUC <- sapply(split(data_example$y, data_example$class), sum)
```

and similarly for the other cases and then `cbind` as in the OP's.  Infact, it can be done on a single `lapply/sapply` too

**2)** As the objects are `list`s, we `unlist` it and then `cbind`

```
data1 <- data.frame(AUC = unlist(AUC),max.y = unlist(max.y), 
   max.x = unlist(max.x), auc.mean = unlist(auc.mean), 
   x.ymax = unlist(x.ymax), class = names(AUC))
```